# Some questions about RMI: Remote Method Invocation

Tags: java, rmi

Iam trying to learn RMI, I do have an RMI example which I got from school. The code is split in three parts. There is an interface **(HelloIF)**, a server **(HelloServer)** and a client **(HelloClient)**. In the server part there is also an implementation of this interface called **HelloImpl**.

Now, in the server they make an object of the HelloImpl. But then they typecast it back to the HelloIF and register this so called stub to the registry. Iam asking myself why they first make an object of HelloImpl and then typecast it back to the HelloIF interface and register this in the registry. So the registry has now the stub object in it? Or just references to the actual remote objects (HelloImpl) right or? Also in RMI they talk about a stub and skeleton, but is this HelloIF stub THE stub or just an unlucky chosen name?

Also can someone explain how RMI works a bit better in plain english? Does the server return an stub object? Or just the return value(s) of the method calls from the remote object on the server.

Server code: (most important)

```
    try {
        logger.debug("Creating stub");
        HelloImpl obj = new HelloImpl();
        HelloIF stub = (HelloIF) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, 0);

        logger.debug("Locating registry on host '" + hostname + "'");
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(hostname);
        logger.debug("Trying to register stub using name '" +    HelloIF.servicename + "'");
        registry.rebind(HelloIF.servicename, stub);
        logger.debug("Stub registered");

        logger.info("Server ready");
  }
```

HelloIF Interface code:

```
package example.interfaces.hello;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface HelloIF extends Remote {

    public static final String servicename = "Hello";

    String sayHello() throws RemoteException;
}
```

Client code:(most important)

```
 try {
        logger.debug("Locating registry on " + hostname);
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(hostname);

       logger.info("Contents of registry: " + Arrays.toString(registry.list()));

       HelloIF stub = (HelloIF) registry.lookup(HelloIF.servicename);
       logger.info("Found '" + HelloIF.servicename + "' in registry");

       logger.trace("Calling sayhello()");
       String response = stub.sayHello();
       logger.info("Response: " + response);
   }
```

Comment: Please *please* don't post screenshots. Just copypaste your code, as a bonus it's easier.

Comment: Have a look at : http://docencia.ac.upc.edu/FIB/PXC/manel/LAB/tut_3.html

Comment: Refer http://www.javatpoint.com/RMI which also explains concepts with example

Comment: Oh please. Forget this arbitrary Internet junk and have a look at the [Oracle RMI Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

> they make an object of the HelloImpl.

Correct.

> But then they typecast it back to the HelloIF

Incorrect. See below.

> and register this so-called stub to the Registry.

There is no 'so-called' about it. It *is* a stub.

> I am asking myself why they first make an object of HelloImpl and then typecast it back to the HelloIF interface and register this in the registry.

They *don't* 'typecast it back to the `HelloIF` interface'. They export the object, via `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject()`, which has a return type of `Remote`, and returns the stub, and they typecast *that* to `HelloIF`. Look it up.

> So the registry has now the stub object in it?

Correct.

> Or just references to the actual remote objects (HelloImpl) right?

No, see above.

> Also in RMI they talk about a stub and skeleton, but is this HelloIF stub THE stub or just an unlucky chosen name?

It is the stub. Anything you read about skeletons is seriously out of date. A different mechanism was introduced in 1998, and became the default in about 2003.

> Does the server return an stub object?

No. The question doesn't make sense. The *Registry* returns the stub object, via `lookup()`. The server returns whatever the remote method(s) it implements return(s).

> Or just the return value(s) of the method calls from the remote object on the server.

Yes.